# Creating argo cd applicationset that will allow an empty (umbrella) helm chart with many sub charts and having hierarchical values file override

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argocd

Assuming I have clusters registered with label: cluster-env with values: dev, prod) and this folder structure for my helm based deployments and I have a microservices based helm deployment in root-umbrella-app (consisting of multiple sub charts),
I want to have this override hierarchy when deploying subchart:  root-umbrella-app/public-web/
root-umbrella-app/values.dev.yaml >>> root-umbrella-app/values.yaml >>>> root-umbrella-app/public-web/values.yaml

```
└── helm-charts-apps
    ├── app1
    │   ├── Chart.yaml
    │   ├── values.yaml
    │   ├── values.dev.yaml
    │   └── values.prod.yaml
    ├── root-umbrella-app
    │   ├── helm-charts
    │   │   ├── public-web
    │   │   │   └── values.yaml # Values for public-web
    │   │   ├── product-api
    │   │   │   └── values.yaml # Values for product-api
    │   │   ├── cart-api
    │   │   │   └── values.yaml # Values for cart-api
    │   │   └── postgres-db
    │   │       └── values.yaml # Values for postgres-db
    │   ├── values.yaml # Root-level default values
    │   ├── values.dev.yaml
    │   └── values.prod.yaml
```

This is what I have untill now. How to achieve this for a complex deployments like root-umbrella-app?
I don't know how to reference: root-umbrella-app/public-web/values.yaml in applicationset
Can this umbrella chart be of application type and sub charts' of library type

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: my-app-set
spec:
  generators:
    - matrix:
        generators:
          - clusters:
              selector:
                matchLabels:
                  cluster-env: "*"
          - git:
              repoURL: https://github.com/myrepo/my-helm-charts.git
              revision: HEAD
              directories:
                - path: helm-charts-apps/* # Path to the Helm chart applications directory
  template:
    metadata:
      name: '{{cluster.metadata.name}}-{{path.basename}}'
    spec:
      project: default
      source:
        repoURL: https://github.com/myrepo/my-helm-charts.git
        targetRevision: HEAD
        chart: {{path}} # Path to the specific Helm chart
        helm:
          valueFiles:
            # - how to reference child helm values.yaml file which should be override by below files. Some default values are only set here and there is no need to override them later
            - values.yaml # Default values file in the Helm chart directory
            - values.{{cluster.metadata.labels.cluster-env}}.yaml # Environment-specific values file
      destination:
        server: '{{cluster.spec.server}}'
        namespace: '{{path.basename}}' (edited)
```

Comment: Hi, do you want `root-umbrella-app` to be an ArgoCD application on itself (app of apps), or are you just using it to organize the repo structure?

Comment: I need an advise. As it is, it is an application that will during helm rendering use argo cd and iterate over sub charts (which I think I need to define in dependency section of umbrella chart). If I had app of apps, maybe I need different applicationset definition. What will that get me? a way to independently deploy applications (microservices) and have roll backs? In that case I "must" have application definitions for each microservice (dependency of main umbrella chart), which I wanted to avoid in the first place. I intend to use phases and wavers to define order deployment of my resources